# I am learning python and iv task my self on building rock paper scissors but i cant get my compeer function to work

Tags: python

When the compeer function runs it will seem to just skip the first if and just go on to the else even though both the random number and user input are the same. My guess is that by the time the Compeer function is called the random number and user input are forgotten somehow. I'm not sure how that would happen but that is my guess. I did have it as a char input eg(r for rock and so on) so I changed it to numbers just to see if that worked but it didn't.

```
import random
import os


print("Press 1 for rock")
print("Press 2 for paper")
print("Press 3 for scissors")

global UserInput

UserInput = input('')

clearConsole = lambda: os.system('cls' if os.name in ('nt', 'dos') else 'clear')

clearConsole()

def User():
    
    if UserInput == '1':
        print("You played Rock")

    elif UserInput == '2':
        print("You played Paper")

    elif UserInput == '3':
        print("You played Scissors")

#print("Computer played" + " " + Computer())


def ComputerPlay():
    if Computer == '1':
        print("Computer played Rock")

    elif Computer == '2':
        print("Computer played Paper")

    elif Computer == '3':
        print("Computer played Scissors")


def Computer():
    smallest = 1
    largest = 4
    global random_number

    random_number = random.randint(smallest, largest - 1)

    if random_number == 1:
        print('Computer played Rock')

    elif random_number == 2:
        print('Computer played Paper')
    
    elif random_number == 3:
        print('Computer played Scissors')

    
def Compeer():
    if random_number == UserInput:
        print("Its a draw")

    else:
        print("Error")


    



User()
Computer()
Compeer()
```

Comment: You are comparing an int with a string. `input()` returns a string, like `"3"`, randint returns an int like `3`, and `3`!= `"3"`

Comment: Also, you have both `Computer()` as a function, and `Computer` as a variable, and it's not clear what the relationship between the two is meant to be. If they're related, you need to call the function like `Computer()`, if they're unrelated you need to use different variable names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem here is that you're mixing strings (like you get from `input()`) with ints (like you get from `randint`).  Since most of the time you're using strings in your code, I'd suggest sticking with that, and converting `randint`'s result to a string -- or using `random.choice` to just select among random strings.

I'd also suggest using parameters to pass information into your various functions, rather than using `global` variables -- your code gets very confusing very quickly when you're using global variables, since it gets hard to keep track of what variables each function uses and modifies.

You can also simplify a lot of your `print` statements by storing the mapping between the numeric choices and what to print for each in a dict.

```
import random
import os

plays = {
    '1': 'Rock',
    '2': 'Paper',
    '3': 'Scissors'
}

def clear_console():
    os.system('cls' if os.name in ('nt', 'dos') else 'clear')

def get_user_play():
    for n, play in plays.items():
        print(f"Press {n} for {play}")
    return input()

def get_computer_play():
    return random.choice("123")

def compare_plays(user_play, computer_play):
    if user_play == computer_play:
        print("Its a draw")
    else:
        print("Error")


user = get_user_play()
computer = get_computer_play()
clear_console()
print(f"You played {plays[user]}")
print(f"Computer played {plays[computer]}")
compare_plays(user, computer)
```

In the above code, `get_user_play` and `get_computer_play` both return a `str`.  When we say:

```
user = get_user_play()
computer = get_computer_play()
```

we're calling those functions, and assigning the results to the variables `user` and `computer` respectively.  We can then print them out:

```
print(f"You played {plays[user]}")
print(f"Computer played {plays[computer]}")
```

and pass them to `compare_plays`:

```
compare_plays(user, computer)
```

Answer (score 1):

input() always gives a string as an input and you took that into account when you made User(), since you compare it against strings, but at the end, you compare a string against an integer. To fix it, wrap the input in int() and make appropriate comparison changes.

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for helping and answering questions. Please just note that answers require detailed information and mainly actual code to answer the OP's issue (or at least example), and if there are already answers, you need to provide with additional info ;-) If you need additional detail from OP (not the case here, it's just for your information), use comment instead ;-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems within this code that are causing you not to see any results. The most prominent being that your user input will still take in a string as opposed to an integer.
To fix this you will need to do int(input('')) instead of what you currently have.

However, I don't think this is the main issue. I would recommend rewriting this script so that you get a better sense of how functions take parameters and how to pass functions from one to another. I've provided a general structure to this program that I'd recommend.

If you're going to use functions for this script, I would pass the needed components to the end function.

Instead of calling User(), Computer() and Compeer() separately, I would call Compeer(User(), Computer()) and rewrite the each of the other functions to return variables to use in your end comparison.

```
def User():
   #Return User Input
```

```
def Computer():
   #Create and return Random Number
```

```
def Compeer(user_input, computer_input):
   #Write out what each of them played and declare a winner in this code
```

Now you just need to call the following

```
Compeer(User(),Computer())
```

This is how I'd prefer the structure and I think it's helpful familiarizing yourself with how to take parameters and how to better design functions in the future.

If you'd like me to further clarify any of this let me know. Thanks.